# C++ "const std::any &" more copy constructor call than without std::any

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++20, any

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <any>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MyVector {
private:
    int n;
    T* data;
public:
    MyVector() {
        n = 0;
        data = nullptr;
        cout << "MyVector default constructor\n";
    }

    MyVector(int _n) {
        n = _n;
        data = new T[n];
        cout << "MyVector param constructor\n";
    }

    MyVector(const MyVector& other) {
        n = other.n;
        data = new T[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) data[i] = other.data[i];
        cout << "MyVector copy constructor\n";
    }

    MyVector(MyVector&& other) {
        n = other.n;
        data = other.data;
        other.n = 0;
        other.data = nullptr;
        cout << "MyVector move constructor\n";
    }

    MyVector& operator = (const MyVector& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            n = other.n;
            delete[] data;
            data = new T[n];
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) data[i] = other.data[i];
        }
        cout << "MyVector copy assigment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    MyVector& operator = (MyVector&& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            n = other.n;
            delete[] data;
            data = other.data;
            other.n = 0;
            other.data = nullptr;
        }
        cout << "MyVector move assigment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ~MyVector() {
        delete[] data;
        cout << "MyVector destructor: size = " << n << "\n";
    }

    int size() {
        return n;
    }
};

template <typename T>
any func_any(const any &vec) {
    cout << "\nBefore func_any assignment\n";
    MyVector<T> res = any_cast<MyVector<T>>(vec); // I want res to const reference MyVector<T> vec, not copy
    cout << "\nAfter func_any assignment\n";
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
MyVector<T> func(const MyVector<T> &vec) {
    cout << "\nBefore func assignment\n";
    MyVector<T> res = vec;
    cout << "\nAfter func assignment\n";
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    MyVector<int> a(5);
    MyVector<int> a2(6);
    cout << "-----------";

    cout << "\nBefore func_any call\n";
    auto b = func_any<int>(a);
    cout << "\nAfter func_any call\n";
    cout << "--------------";

    cout << "\nBefore func call\n";
    auto c = func<int>(a2);
    cout << "\nAfter func call\n";

    cout << "-----------------";
    cout << "\nBefore exit\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make a function-executor base class with Python like interface (use `std::any` as input and output). In each child class, the actual type input type is known at compile time, so I wish to cast `std::any` to a specific type. In the example above I just use a function to make it simple.

However, the function with `std::any` call constructors and destructors many times more than the function without. The above program give the following input:

```
MyVector param constructor
MyVector param constructor
-----------
Before func_any call
MyVector copy constructor

Before func_any assignment
MyVector copy constructor

After func_any assignment
MyVector move constructor
MyVector destructor: size = 0
MyVector destructor: size = 5

After func_any call
--------------
Before func call

Before func assignment
MyVector copy constructor

After func assignment

After func call
-----------------
Before exit
MyVector destructor: size = 6
MyVector destructor: size = 5
MyVector destructor: size = 6
MyVector destructor: size = 5
```

So the function version that uses `std::any` needs 3 constructor + 2 destructor calls. While the normal version needs just 1 constructor call. I assume the `return` statement in `func` is copy elision.

How can I improve this? **The most important thing I need is below**, if it's impossible with `std::any` then please provide a possible solution with `std::variant`.

`MyVector<T> res = any_cast<MyVector<T>>(vec); // I want res to const reference MyVector<T> vec, not copy`

Comment: You first convert a _vector_ `a2` to _any_ `vec`. Then, you convert this _any_ `vec` to _vector_ `res`. Finally, you again convert _vector_ `res` to _any_ `b`. Why so many conversions? What is the reason for converting from _any_ to _vector_ and then back to _any_? It's similar as in this live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/n5eMrrG55.

Comment: It was just to demonstrate constructor/destructor with std::any. In my actual usage the function return something else, not `res`

Comment: `vector res = ...` – you instantiate a new vector. Wouldn't you rather want a reference? `vector& res = std::any_cast<vector&>(...)`?

Comment: You can use `const MyVector<int>& res = any_cast<const MyVector<int>&>(vec);` to avoid copy.

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: @Aconcagua I tried that and got compiler error. Turns out I forgot to add const. Thanks!

Comment: Not fully sure what you intend to do – but sounds a bit like *polymorphism* might be a good alternative. Have you considered?

Comment: @Aconcagua I'm making a generic executor that receives a map<string,map<string,std::any>>, parse the string for function name, then parse the map inside for parameter. So I need a function that can accept any type of parameter and return std::any. I don't know if it's possible with polymorph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object needs to be copied into the `std::any`, so trying to call `func_any<int>(a)` will copy `a`.

You can instead hold a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` or a `T*` pointer in the `std::any`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
any func_any(const any &vec) {
    cout << "\nBefore func_any assignment\n";
    MyVector<T> res = any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<const MyVector<T>>>(vec);
    cout << "\nAfter func_any assignment\n";
    return res;
}

auto b = func_any<int>(std::cref(a));
```

Since you already know what types are actually being used, you might be better off making your base class use `void*` as input and output.

---

You can also [`any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) to a reference type:

```cpp
const MyVector<T>& res = std::any_cast<const MyVector<T>&>(vec)
```

This will be a reference to the value held in `vec` (so no constructors involved). This will not reduce the overall number of copies, but it will get rid of one move due to NRVO.

Comment: I forgot the const keyword in my `std::any_cast<MyVector<T>&>(vec)` . Thanks!

Comment: Oh, any_cast to reference still cost a copy. So I guess I have to use reference_wrapper

Comment: @HuyLe It shouldn't be. The copy should be happening when you pass it as a parameter (`func_any(const any& vec)` binds to a tempory `std::any` that copies)